# Set first date of the year when only it has only the year in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column name called `date` in one pandas dataframe, this are the first 10 rows:

```
0    22-Oct-2022
1     3-Dec-2019
2    27-Jun-2022
3           2023
4    15-Jul-2017
5           2019
6     7-Sep-2022
7           2021
8    30-Sep-2022
9    17-Aug-2021
```

I want convert all those dates to for example:

```
0    2023-05-19 
1    2023-01-20 
2    ...
```

And for those rows that only has the year I want set it to for example, if the original `df` has:

```
0           2019
1           2021
```

to

```
5           2019-01-01
7           2021-01-01
```

In other words I mean I want set for this cases set the first date of the year but keeping the original year not the current year.

I tried:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', format='%d-%b-%Y')
```

However it's generating `NaT` values. I hope that you understand this case guys, I will appreciate any idea to fix this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the *format* as `mixed` (New in [`2.0.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#other-enhancements), see [*GH50972*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50972)) when calling [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :

> `format` : *str, default None*
>
> "mixed", **to infer the format for each element individually**. This is
> risky, and you should probably use it along with dayfirst.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="mixed", dayfirst=True)
```

Or a classical double *date-parsing* + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df["date"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce", format="%Y")
        .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce", dayfirst=True))
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

        date
0 2022-10-22
1 2019-12-03
2 2022-06-27
3 2023-01-01
4 2017-07-15
5 2019-01-01
6 2022-09-07
7 2021-01-01
8 2022-09-30
9 2021-08-17
```

Comment: best solution with: df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="mixed")
last approach is throwing NaT . Big Thanks sir.

Comment: In this particular case `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])` also works without `format` or `errors` arguments.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, in `2.0.1`, your code throws a `ValueError: time data "2023" doesn't match format "%d-%b-%Y", at position 3.`

Comment: @Timeless: Good catch.  I was using 1.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to update the values manually, first you can standarize the rows that only have the year like this:

```py
condition = data['date'].length == 4
data.loc[condition, 'date'] = '1-Jan' + df['date'].astype(str)
```

and then try to use the `to_datetime` function on the result